# Writing null-terminated char array into object class with char array

Tags: arrays, string, heap-memory, stack-memory

First of all I want to say that I'm new to `C++` and this is a homework assignment. Also, I am not sure I am using the correct definitions in the title so correct me if I'm wrong.

I have to make a string class that stores the contents of a null-terminated char array. If the length of the input is larger than 32, store it on the heap, else store it on the stack.

Right now I'm busy with the constructor:

```
 #include "SString.h"   
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SString::SString(const char* input)
{
    // Determine length of input
    int length = 0;
    while (input[length] != '\0')
    {
        length++; 
    }
    // Check for zero length
    if (length == 0)
    {
        st_string[1] = ' ';
    }
    // Based on length, make heap string or use stack string
    if(length > 32) 
    {
        int i = 0;
        p_string = new char[length];
        while (i != length) //write string with input
        {
            p_string[i] = input[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i != length) //write string with input
        {
            st_string[i] = input[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << "saved string:" << endl;
    cout << p_string << endl;
}
```

Now I tested this by calling the SimpleString with a string like this in the main:

```
 SString("test"); // or something
```

It works, putting the string on either the `st_string` or `p_string` but in both cases the stored string has more (strange undefined) characters at the end. So in the case of "test", I get test#54 or something.

I'm guessing it makes the saved char array larger than the inputted char array but I cant see why.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while (i != length)` loops do not copy the final `\0` inside the new character array. You should change them to

```
while (i <= length) //write string with input
{
    appropriate_string[i] = input[i];
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with your code. First, what exactly is the point of:

```
// Check for zero length
if (length == 0)
{
    st_string[1] = ' ';
}
```

? If the rest of the code is at all robust, the empty-string case will be handled naturally. All you're doing here is making it so that your class can't reliably be used if there are spaces in the original string.

As to why you're getting the particular error you're asking about - think about what you're doing when you copy character-by-character. Your original string is this:

`t e s t \0`

and `length` is 4. That means your loop farther down will be copying 4 characters into the local array. Do you see the problem here yet?

> I'm guessing it makes the saved char array larger than the inputted char array but i cant see why.

Quite the opposite, in fact. See, the part I left out was what comes *after* your string in memory. The original is:

`t e s t \0 # # # #`

where the `#`'s are basically random bytes. The string is being copied so that it becomes:

`t e s t # # # #`

because you didn't copy the \0. The loop that reads the string back out will keep going until it hits a null byte - but you have no way of knowing where that will be because you didn't put one there yourself. If it happens to get dropped in memory so that it looks like this:

`t e s t \54 \0 # # #`

then you'll only get one garbage character, but it could be much more. So actually, in a way you *are* getting a longer string saved than you intended, but not in the normal sense.

Comment: This clarifies it for me. Thanks for the comments guys!

Answer (score 0):

after your while loop's where you copy characters one by one, just after this while loop you need to add end of string character to your varaible  like

```
st_string[i] = '\0';
```